# Inject non-const variable into all templates in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to know how can I inject variable into all twig templates. The most important thing is that my variable won't be const and I must use some logic from controller to prepare data. In other words, I want to create form using formBuilder (so I must use controller functions) and make it global - it means access to form view from all views (templates).

I can do that in this way:

```
// this is part of my controller
return $this->render('AcmeBundle:Homepage:index.html.twig', array(
        "myForm" => $myForm->createView(),
    ));
```

And copy it into all controller, but this is very ugly solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject variable into all templates http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html. You can also reference a service http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html#referencing-services. So you can do there common logic.